# Is the purpose of questions to get an answer or spread knowledge?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope, close-reasons

I was just reading this question: [JS: Why Is This Slower? It Shouldn't Test Other OR Conditions But It Does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24564902/js-why-is-this-slower-it-shouldnt-test-other-or-conditions-but-it-does)

And it seems as though both from the comments, and from the lack of answers that it doesn't have a clearly defined answer. It's a "code optimization thing" rather than a "this is the answer" thing.

But from the upvotes, and comments people clearly thought it was worth asking or reading because it's a source of knowledge.

Where's the line between this type of question and questions that are closed because they don't have an answer or are primarily opinion based? Does a question have to have an answer,  or is it enough that it spreads knowledge?

Comment: The answer is actually *"to make money for the company"* this is done by people who need questions answered, and people answering questions to form a knowledge base

Comment: Getting an answer does spread knowledge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd argue that both are true.

On the one hand, you have a problem that you can't solve and need an answer to get you to a solution. This is both getting an answer and sharing knowledge for future users, as long as the question is on topic, not too localized etc...

On the other hand, SO encourages people to share knowledge that may help others in future as you can [answer your own questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). So this is simply spreading knowledge, but as a side effect, you may get a better solution that would improve your understanding.

> Stack Exchange has always explicitly encouraged  users to answer
>   their own questions. If you have a question that you already know the
>   answer to, and you would like to document that knowledge in public so
>   that others (including yourself) can find it later, it's perfectly
>   okay to ask and answer your own question on a Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 4):

Both. A question should incite an answer, which together spread knowledge.

In this particular case, I bet people thought the question is interesting because it's reasonably well presented, offers a non-trivial problem and surfaces a piece of trivia many people may not have been aware of. Whatever the exact answer to the question, this sounds like a decent question. And this certainly is an *answerable* question, whether it be a trivial but non-obvious answer or simply hard to answer precisely. Just apparently nobody has gotten around to writing up a good answer yet. Maybe we're waiting for a compiler expert here.